# Why I don't have to declaire the listener in the configuration?

Tags: grails, spring-batch

I have a processor that implements StepExecutionListener. The bean is declared in the takslet as a procesor and not as a listener, but the method afterStep is even so called. Is it normal that there is no need to declare the listener ? My configuration :

```
batch.step(id: 'myStep') {
    batch.tasklet {
        batch.chunk(
            reader : 'myReader',
            processor: 'myProcessor',
            writer : 'myWriter',
            'commit-interval' : 1000)
    }
    batch.next(on: 'FAILED', to: 'failStep')
    batch.next(on: '*', to: 'myOtherStep')
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tasklet' reader, writer and processor are automatically registered as listeners if implements StepListener interface or are marked with specific annotations

Comment: Thank you. Is it only for the grails plugin, or a spring batch feature ?

Comment: It is a SB feature. It is written somewhere in official docs. And I suppose in one or more SO answer

Comment: Ok thanks, I've got it : https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html#interceptingStepExecution (An ItemReader, ItemWriter or ItemProcessor that itself implements one of the StepListener interfaces will be registered automatically with the Step if using the namespace <step> element, or one of the the *StepFactoryBean factories)